# Deploy using git with different settings per local/hosted environment

Tags: amazon-web-services, git, deployment

I'm new to Git and planning to use it to deploy a PHP application to AWS Elasitic Beanstalk environment. I don't know how to handle the database configuration or anything else that needs different settings per environment such as the .htaccess file.

Since I'm using the Yii framework I need to change the config array depending on whether I'm on the local/AWS environment which looks like so:

```
        'db'=>array(
        'connectionString' => 'mysql:host={host};dbname={dbname}',
        'emulatePrepare' => true,
        'username' => '{username}',
        'password' => '{password}',
        'charset' => 'utf8',
    ),
```

How do I deploy with Git but keep different settings for local/AWS environments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use separate branch, say, "production", which would have own version of the config, and simply merge ready-for-production changes there.